# Can be Bash Script used to automate proces for multiple files in an open program? for exmaple GIMP?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gimp

So i know to open a program, i just have to type the name of the program in.

Example:

```
#! /bin/bash
gimp
```

now i wanna know can i use this script to send like commands to gimp. Like open Gimp and then in Gimp go to command open > and then read the given folder with the images in it.

For example what i want is :

Open gimp > read a given folder > open all images in there one by one > and does some filter to it > then save it

is there a way to do this? Is there a way to do this with Python?

Thanks for the Answers.

Answer (score 2):

Type `gimp --help` or `man gimp` on command line and see a list of options (online version: https://www.gimp.org/man/gimp.html )

The gimp website also has a page dedicated to [batch mode](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/).

Generally batch mode is to execute actions on a or multiple files.

So this:

> Open gimp > read a given folder > open all images in there one by one > and does some filter to it > then save it

becomes:

- use `gimp -b` and add behind it the files and the action for your filter.

No need to open gimp, nor to tell it the folder name (you can `cd` into it prior to the command) and saving it will be done automatically.

This one will be of interest but it is in its native language so not python:

> Processing several files
>
> You might want to apply an effect to a number of files, typically to a set of files in the same directory. GIMP 2.2 added a very useful function for this purpose, the file-glob plug-in. This turns GIMP into a versatile batch processor. In order to use it, we will need to do some modifications to our script:

```
 (define (batch-unsharp-mask pattern
                              radius
                              amount
                              threshold)
  (let* ((filelist (cadr (file-glob pattern 1))))
    (while (not (null? filelist))
           (let* ((filename (car filelist))
                  (image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                              filename filename)))
                  (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))))
             (plug-in-unsharp-mask RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                   image drawable radius amount threshold)
             (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                             image drawable filename filename)
             (gimp-image-delete image))
           (set! filelist (cdr filelist)))))
```

> This version of the script takes a glob pattern instead of a filename and will apply the Unsharp Mask filter to all files matching this pattern. In order to sharpen all PNG images in the current directory, you would run the following command:

```
gimp -i -b '(batch-unsharp-mask "*.png" 5.0 0.5 0)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

---

If you want python use the module for it. Random example using  "gimp-text-layer-new"

```
import gi
from gi.repository import Gimp
result = Gimp.get_pdb().run_procedure(
  'gimp-text-layer-new',
  [image, text, font_name, font_size, 3]
)
layer = result.index(1)
```

Comment: The batch one worked for me. But the python didnt work it said IndentationError: unexpected Indent.  However if i would use python i think it would be more useful. Do you know if i want to read two folders with the same amount images and same names then open them one by one in Gimp then merge them and export them how the code would be look? i really dont know much python. so my idea is a python script batch > open gimp > read first folder with (n) images open 1. the read second folder open 1. there > merge them and export them. i would be really thankful if you would help me.

Comment: Make sure to indent with 2 or 4 spaces or a tab Python is picky about that  ;) but merging 2 images I would use "convert" from imagemagick not gimp.

Comment: convert is a lot easier for this: see for some examples https://superuser.com/a/290679/276585

Comment: could you help me out for like reading two folders and merging them what code do i have to do? 
`set FOLDER_A=\blah\blah
set FOLDER_B=\another\blah
set FOLDER_OUT=\out_blah

for %%F in (%FOLDER_A%\a*.png) do (
  if exist %FOLDER_B%\%%~nxF %IM%convert %%F %FOLDER_B%\%%~nxF +append %FOLDER_OUT%\%%~nxF
)` something like this i found it, but it doesn't work